# How to retrieve values of textboxes in JSF managed bean which are generated through a loop?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to generate textboxes through a loop as follows.

```
<p:panel id="dataPanel"  closable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal" toggleable="true" header="Data">
    <h:panelGrid id="dataPanelGrid" columns="3" cellpadding="5">

        <c:forEach var="row" items="#{zoneChargeManagedBean.list}">

            <p:outputLabel for="txtCharge" value="#{row[1]}"/>          

            <p:inputText id="txtCharge" value="#{row[2]}" converter="#{bigDecimalConverter}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event, this.value);" label="#{row[1]}" required="false" maxlength="45">
                <f:validator validatorId="negativeNumberValidator"/>
                <f:attribute name="isZeroAllowed" value="false"/>

                <f:validator validatorId="bigDecimalRangeValidator"/>
                <f:attribute name="minPrecision" value="1"/>
                <f:attribute name="maxPrecision" value="33"/>
                <f:attribute name="scale" value="2"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <p:message for="txtCharge" showSummary="false"/>

        </c:forEach>

        <p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="dataPanel messages" actionListener="#{zoneChargeManagedBean.insert}" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Save"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="dataPanel" process="@this">
            <p:resetInput target="dataPanel" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

The value of the given textbox is a type of `BigDecimal` from the database.

When the given command button is pressed, the values held by these textboxes should be retrieved from the corresponding JSF managed bean so that they can either be inserted or updated in the database.

It would be even better, if it is possible to retrieve the values of all of these text fields at once in some kind of collection (like `java.util.List`), when the given button is pressed.

Comment: You can use PrimeFaces DataTable - Rowediting feature. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf

Comment: Question is unclear to me. ZoneChargeManagedBean is your code and you should know best how to access its data. Using indices to access rows data seems awkward by the way but hard to tell any more without bean's code.

Comment: What exactly is your concrete problem? You already have a `#{zoneChargeManagedBean.list}` to hold the values. Is it empty when you check it in action method or so?

Comment: The new values are not accumulated in `zoneChargeManagedBean.list`, of course when used with `<c:foreEach>` which doesn't happen with `<ui:repeate>` in which it is populated with the new values (the list is already populated while retrieving from the database, if there are corresponding rows in the database table. The update needs to be taken place only in the last element of the object array `row[2]`  held by the list. The values of this last element are displayed in `<p:inputText>`).

Comment: Oh right, you're still using Spring to manage beans. Apparently its view scope is incompatible with `c:forEach` which causes the bean to be recreated on every iteration. A similar bug existed in JSF's own view scope in older Mojarra versions. In the future questions please describe the actual problem! (and eliminate code noise, I don't see how using a `BigDecimal` instead of `String` and having those validators/converters, `<p:panel>`, etc..etc.. are ever relevant to the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC : Yes I have already read many of your answers regrading this. Thank you.

Comment: @mrembisz - Why would it be awkward to access data (`List`) by its indices? Many a times, it is a usual case such as while getting only selected columns from a database table. It returns a list of arrays of objects in such cases.

Comment: @erencan - `DataTable` is completely unnecessary in this case. The poster only wants to display text boxes dynamically in a tabular format. `DataGrid` as it is used by the poster in his answer is more appropriate which also supports pagination and other required functions like `DataTable`.

Comment: @Lion It is more readable to have a list of meaningful business objects (instead of list of lists) as a model where objects have properties to be shown in respective columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ui:repeate>`, a render time tag works correctly but not `<c:foreEach>`, a view build time component (I can't clarify why) but in this particular case, I found `<p:dataGrid>` is more suitable. The XHTML has been modified accordingly as follows.

```
<p:panel id="dataPanel" rendered="#{zoneChargeManagedBean.renderedDataPanel}" closable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal" toggleable="true" header="Data">
    <p:dataGrid columns="3" value="#{zoneChargeManagedBean.list}" var="row" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" pageLinks="10" rows="15">
        <p:watermark for="txtCharge" value="Enter charge."/>
        <p:tooltip for="lblCharge" value="Some message."/>

        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel id="lblCharge" for="txtCharge" value="#{row[1]}"/><br/>
            <p:inputText id="txtCharge" value="#{row[2]}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event, this.value);" converter="#{bigDecimalConverter}" label="#{row[1]}" required="false" maxlength="45">
                <f:validator validatorId="negativeNumberValidator"/>
                <f:attribute name="isZeroAllowed" value="false"/>

                <f:validator validatorId="bigDecimalRangeValidator"/>
                <f:attribute name="minPrecision" value="1"/>
                <f:attribute name="maxPrecision" value="33"/>
                <f:attribute name="scale" value="2"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <h:message for="txtCharge" showSummary="false" style="color: #F00;"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="dataPanel messages" actionListener="#{zoneChargeManagedBean.insert}" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Save"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="dataPanel" process="@this">
        <p:resetInput target="dataPanel" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:panel>
```

---

The managed bean:

```
@Controller
@Scope("view")
public final class ZoneChargeManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient ZoneChargeService zoneChargeService=null;
    private ZoneTable selectedZone;     //Getter and setter
    private List<Object[]>list;         //Getter and setter
    private boolean renderedDataPanel;  //Getter and setter

    public ZoneChargeManagedBean() {}

    public void ajaxListener() {
        if(this.selectedZone!=null){
            list=zoneChargeService.getZoneChargeList(this.selectedZone.getZoneId());
            renderedDataPanel=true;
        }
        else {
            renderedDataPanel=false;
        }
    }

    public void insert() {
        //Just do whatever is needed based on the list with new values which is retrieved when <p:commandButton> as shown in the given XHTML is clicked.

        if(selectedZone!=null&&zoneChargeService.addOrUpdate(list, selectedZone)) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Message Summary", "Message"));
        }
        else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Message Summary", "Message"));
        }
    }
}
```

The service method as in the `ajaxListener()` method returns a list of type of an array of objects - `List<Object[]>`.

```
public List<Object[]>getZoneChargeList(Long id) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select w.weightId, w.weight, zc.charge from Weight w left join w.zoneChargeSet zc with zc.zoneTable.zoneId=:id order by w.weight").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
}
```

<sub>I can't use the corresponding JPA criteria query which is intended because the `with` operator which doesn't seem to be supported by the JPA criteria API.</sub>

This method is invoked when an item from `<p:selectOneMenu>` is selected which is not covered in this question.