# How to get a lazily loaded List of p:dataGrid back in the associated JSF managed bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a lazily loaded [`<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml). The corresponding XHTML code is as under.

```
<p:panel id="dataPanel" header="Data">
    <p:dataGrid value="#{testManagedBean}" var="row" columns="3" rows="9" pageLinks="10" paginator="true" lazy="true">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="lblCharge" value="#{row.weight}" converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralOutputConverter}"/><br/>
            <p:inputText id="txtCharge" value="#{row.charge}" converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralConverter}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="page"/>
    </p:dataGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="dataPanel" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.insert}" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="dataPanel" process="@this">
        <p:resetInput target="dataPanel" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:panel>
```

The associated JSF managed bean looks like as show below.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private final ZoneChargeBeanLocal zoneChargeService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<ZoneChargeUtils> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
    {
        setRowCount(zoneChargeService.rowCount(7L).intValue());
        return zoneChargeService.getZoneChargeList(7L, first, pageSize);
    }

    public void insert() {
        System.out.println("insert() called.");
    }
}
```

The data grid displays a group of `<p:inputText>`s that looks something like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TWT5.png).

[image]

A user can modify values held by `<p:inputText>` as can be seen in the snap shot. The modified values are to be stored into the database, when the given `<p:commandButton>` (save) immediately below the data grid is pressed.

The associated action listener `insert()` is invoked, when this `<p:commandButton>` is pressed but how to get these modified values in that action listener so that they can be sent to the database in question?

This can be done avoiding lazy loading as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17860451/1391249). This is the exact same scenario but with lazy loading.

How to get the list, `List<ZoneChargeUtils>` with new / modified values in `<p:inputText>`, when the given `<p:commandButton>` is clicked?

---

The utility class `ZoneChargeUtils` though completely unnecessary.

```
public final class ZoneChargeUtils implements Serializable
{
    private Long weightId;
    private BigDecimal weight;
    private BigDecimal charge;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Getters and setters + constructor(s).
}
```

<sub>This is not a persistent entity / POJO. It is used to execute queries with constructor expressions in JPA</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the following approach using the [`getWrappedData()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html#getWrappedData%28%29) method of `LazyDataModel<T>` works as expected.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private final ZoneChargeBeanLocal zoneChargeService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<ZoneChargeUtils> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
    {
        setRowCount(zoneChargeService.rowCount(7L).intValue());
        return zoneChargeService.getZoneChargeList(7L, first, pageSize);
    }

    public void insert() {
        //Returns the lazily loaded list with the modified values completely appropriate to the page size.
        //Do whatever you want to do with the lazily loaded list now.
        List<ZoneChargeUtils> zoneChargeUtils = (List<ZoneChargeUtils>) getWrappedData();

        for(ZoneChargeUtils utils:zoneChargeUtils) {
            System.out.println(utils.getWeightId()+" : "+utils.getWeight()+" : "+utils.getCharge());
        }
    }
}
```

The `getWrappedData()` method returns the list with **modified values** in `<p:inputText>` according to the page size defined, hence, eliminating the need of extraneous code to get the associated lazily loaded list back in the listener method.

Comment: +1 for you being an autodidact who can answer his own questions, and for providing a nice solution. Are you really 14 ? Good job, nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm 14. Just very unknowingly put my hands into the field of IT with the help of some people though I did not deserve it at all :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem involves keeping two buffers in your `@ViewScoped` managed bean, one for the whole set of the changed values and other one for the current view values. Moreover, you'll need to call a listener method everytime you switch the page to send your current values to the managed bean:

```
<p:panel id="dataPanel" header="Data">
    <p:dataGrid value="#{testManagedBean}" var="row" columns="3" 
        rows="9" pageLinks="10" paginator="true" lazy="true">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="lblCharge" value="#{row.weight}" 
                converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralOutputConverter}"/><br/>
            <p:inputText id="txtCharge" value="#{row.charge}" 
                converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralConverter}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{testManagedBean.pageChanged}"/>
    </p:dataGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="dataPanel" 
        action="#{testManagedBean.insert}" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="dataPanel" process="@this">
        <p:resetInput target="dataPanel" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:panel>
```

I made couple of changes here. One is adding a listener method to the ajax event for the page changing. The other one is replacing `actionListener` by `action` in your `p:commandButton`. `action` is the most convenient way to go when performing business actions like yours.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private final ZoneChargeBeanLocal zoneChargeService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<Integer, ZoneChargeUtils> bufferedZones = new HashMap<Integer, ZoneChargeUtils>();
    private List<ZoneChargeUtils> currentZones = new ArrayList<ZoneChargeUtils>();

    @Override
    public List<ZoneChargeUtils> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
    {
        currentZones.clear();
        setRowCount(zoneChargeService.rowCount(7L).intValue());
        List loadedZones = zoneChargeService.getZoneChargeList(7L, first, pageSize);
        for (ZoneChargeUtils zone : loadedZones){
            if (bufferedZones.containsKey(zone.getId())){
                //The zone has been loaded before in the view. Load the buffered value
                //Otherwise, you'll lose it'll be overwritten with DB value when lazy loading
                currentZones.add(bufferedZones.get(zone.getId()));
            }else{
                currentZones.add(zone);
            }
        }
        return currentZones;
    }

    public void pageChanged(){
        //The user has changed the page. Update bufferedZones with the possible new values
        for (ZoneChargeUtils zone : currentZones){
            bufferedZones.put(zone.getId(), zone);
        }
    }

    //Looks for modified values in the CURRENT page before updating them. 
    //If value isn't there, return the one passed in the param
    private ZoneChargeUtils lookUpInCurrent(ZoneChargeUtils zone){
        for (ZoneChargeUtils z : currentZones){
            if (zone.getId() == z.getId()){
                return z;
            }
        }
        return zone;
    }

    //Persist the values. Look in the general buffer, keeping in mind it has been updated in the last page change. 
    //Because of that, we have to look also in the current buffer for changes made in the current page.
    public void insert() {
        for (ZoneChargeUtils zone : bufferedZones.values()){
            zoneChargeService.updateZone(lookUpInCurrent(zone));
        }
    }
}
```

For the managed bean, you're interested in keeping two values: the changes happened in the current page and the changes for the whole set of loaded pages. I use a `List` for the first one and a `Map` for the second, supposing you already have an Id defined for your `ZoneChargeUtils`. Steps are following:

- When user loads the first page (or any page) the `loadData` method is called for the current value set. In order of returning the persisted values directly, you check them against the whole buffer. If the value has been loaded before, use the buffered value. Otherwise, present the persisted one.
- When user changes the page, update the whole buffer with the current one. That way you are able to keep the modified values.
- When user saves the changes, go to the whole buffer (the `Map`) and iterate over its values. Make an update for each one of the loaded entities.

Comment: Tried. I can see the `Map` `bufferedZones` always remains empty in the `insert()` method. Am I doing it right way? :)

Comment: Does the `pageChanged()` method populate it when you change a page? You should also update `currentZones` one by one when calling insert, otherwise the current page values won't get properly written in the DB. I'll update my example!

Comment: Updated. Hope it to be useful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> The associated action listener insert() is invoked, when this
>    is pressed but how to get these modified values in
>   that action listener so that they can be sent to the database in
>   question?

Store the reference of changed 'entities' in a `HashMap<Integer, ZoneChargeUtils >`. Then execute those changes in insert(), by iterating through that HashMap. You need an ajax value change listener for the `<p:inputText>` to listen to the changes, and in order to modify/update the state storing `HashMap`.

It's slightly different that the solution proposed by **Xtreme Biker**, but the idea is same : Store the state-change in `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

hy all,
First: i m not ok for do @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped in Class TestManagedBean where this Class extend LazyDataModel
the solution is:

```
public final class lazyZoneChargeUtils extends LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> implements Serializable{

@Override
public List<ZoneChargeUtils> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
{
    currentZones.clear();
    setRowCount(zoneChargeService.rowCount(7L).intValue());
    List loadedZones = zoneChargeService.getZoneChargeList(7L, first, pageSize);
    for (ZoneChargeUtils zone : loadedZones){
        if (bufferedZones.containsKey(zone.getId())){
            //The zone has been loaded before in the view. Load the buffered value
            currentZones.add(bufferedZones.get(zone.getId()));
        }else{
            currentZones.add(zone);
        }
    }
    return currentZones;
}
}
```

and :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean {

//all variable 
private LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> listZoneChargeUtils;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    //init listZoneChargeUtils
 this.listZoneChargeUtils = new lazyZoneChargeUtils();
}

public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    ZoneChargeUtils var = (ZoneChargeUtils) event.getObject();
    //do your code and save object in DataBase
}

public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    ZoneChargeUtils var = (ZoneChargeUtils) event.getObject();

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Message : ", var.getName());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

}

/**
 * @return the listZoneChargeUtils
 * 
 * @author asghaier
 *
 * Created on 12/mag/2014
 */
public LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> getListZoneChargeUtils() {
    return listZoneChargeUtils;
}


/**
 * @param listZoneChargeUtils the listZoneChargeUtils to set
 *
 * @author asghaier
 *
 * Created on 12/mag/2014
 */
public void setListZoneChargeUtils(LazyDataModel<ZoneChargeUtils> listZoneChargeUtils) {
    this.listZoneChargeUtils = listZoneChargeUtils;
}
//all getter and setter
}
```

and now in your page do this:

```
<p:panel id="dataPanel" header="Data">
<p:dataGrid value="#{testManagedBean.listZoneChargeUtils}" var="row" columns="3" rows="9" pageLinks="10" paginator="true" lazy="true" editable="true">

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{testManagedBean.onEdit}"  />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{testManagedBean.onCancel}" />

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText id="lblCharge" value="#{row.weight}" converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralOutputConverter}"/><br/>
       <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.charge}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{row.charge}" style="width:100%" converter="#{bigDecimalGeneralConverter}"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>

    </p:column>
    <p:column >  
        <p:rowEditor />  
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

this is in general haw you must do, ( i dont have see good all code).

resume:

1- do class  extends LazyDataModel<...> and dont put any @ManagedBean or @ViewScoped

2- do class @ManagedBeanand and @ViewScoped and in the class creat variable in type 
LazyDataModel<...> listData, implement getter and setter for this variabile, and init the variable listData in methode init() where is @PostConstruct

3- add editable="true" to your dataTable

4- in the class creat in step 2 add method onCancel & onEdit , in the methode onEdit do your code Java and save the object in database.

5- all is ok :)